# Approval workflow: can an approver reject an item that they previously approved?

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-enterprise, designer-workflow

As I understand, the SharePoint 2010 workflow creates Task items for each approval, and once the task is closed (either approved or rejected), that's it. Can this be modified so that approvers can change their mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I can think is to create a custom user control for this, it would have to set the property back to pending. I can't find a way in a normal workflow, and a user control is better than a visual studio workflow in my book.

Comment: We decided to make it clear in the approval email that the Approve/Reject action is final. Thank you for your answer though; you're right that the control would have to set the property back to Pending status.